# Automating a Data Entry Job in Excel with Automator or any other app

Tags: microsoft-excel, automator, macos-highsierra, document-automation

I have to complete labeling process in excel sheet with over 3000 rows.  The excel sheet ( please see atttachment) has three columns, E1, E2, and Label. E1 and E2 are already type in and I need to read each row and based on the relevance of the two E1 and E2, label the row by 0,1, or 2.

What I would like to automate is:

- repeat until last row
- Select the two cells (B10:B11)- I hold shift and use down, left arrows+ hold shift + Press left arrow twice
- Read the two cell (I press alt+Esc)
- move the cursor to the right
- enter my label.

I have a foot pedal that can be programmed. I would like to automate 1-3 by pressing a key on my foot switch or keyboard shortcut, and just enter label. Is it possible to do this with automator? if so, how? if now is there a software to automations like this at the application level and not files and folders?

Another way to do this is having a software that executes a sequence of key strokes and the save it as a macro or so that if we set a key shortcut, we excite them in sequence. Is there a way or a software to do this please?

[image]

Comment: Try to record your actions using macro-recorder.

Comment: you already seem to do it very efficiently, it's not clear what exactly you want to improve.